# How to stop PyCharm's 'smart' tab behaviour

Tags: python, pycharm

The default tab (as in, white space) behaviour of PyCharm appears prevents you from inserting additional tabs where it doesn't think it is appropriate.

Could someone advise how to turn this behaviour off? It works most of the time, but sometimes you need to go back to the previous line and insert a new line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no option to disable it. Instead, you should report the specific cases where it doesn't work as expected so that we can address them, please [use the issue tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/PY).

Comment: In what is otherwise a pretty awesome IDE and editing environment, this seems like an odd restriction to place on the user. I guess I can see the logic behind it as PyCharm will normally always know what is the appropriate level of indentation, but pressing tab and having nothing happen is quite frustrating (even if that tab would lead to an inappropriate indent level). Let me work out where I do or don't want whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Code style settings can be configured in File | Settings | Editor | Code Style | C/C++. Indents can be configured in the Tabs and Indents tab. Also you can disable Smart indent in File | Settings | Editor | General | Smart Keys. More info about reformatting source code -

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/reformatting-source-code.html